# Perform LDAP Ping in C#

Tags: c#, ldap

How would you go about performing the type of LDAP query outlined here, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223811.aspx), in C# (i.e. an LDAP "Ping")? I have been looking at `DirectorySearcher` and `LdapConnection` in S.DS.P, but haven't been able to craft an actual filter string that receives any response. Or is this something that would need to be P/Invoke'd?

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more on WHY you would want to do such a thing? I ask because, when given the right parameters, S.DS.P will already automatically perform CLDAP Pings and connect to the "nearest" available domain controller. So if all you want to do is try and figure out which domain controllers are nearby and available before you actually try to attempt to connect to it, I'm saying that you don't have to do that. I will gladly write an answer explaining more on why, if that is your use case. However, if you have some other use case, then I can give a pointer that may help instead.

Answer (score 1):

The code below performs an LDAP ping to get LDAP site information following the protocol definitions in the [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/895a7744-aff3-4f64-bcfa-f8c05915d2e9) site.

The part I had the most difficulty with was the documentation in [Name Decompression Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b0ef9479-78d8-40c1-b6d2-0baad834ed39) which put me on the right track but has a bug in it and I had to refer to the definition in [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) (section 4.1.4 Message compression) to resolve. I have added comments where my code differs from the [Microsoft Learn Name Decompression Algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b0ef9479-78d8-40c1-b6d2-0baad834ed39).

It wasn't clear in the documentation but in practice it looks like you need to filter on at least the NtVer field plus one other field before you get a response.

I have tested this code in Windows and Ubuntu 22.04 in .NET 6.

Hopefully this is of use to somebody...

Requires nugets System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myDomain = "mydomain";

        LdapPingResponseEx responseEx = LdapUtils.LdapPingCheckDomain(myDomain, myDomain);

        Console.WriteLine($"Ldap Server name: {responseEx.DnsHostName}"); 
        Console.WriteLine($"Site where Ldap Server is located: {responseEx.DcSiteName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Site where client (this machine) is located: {responseEx.ClientSiteName}");

    }
```

LdapUtils class

```
   internal static class LdapUtils
    {
        #region members

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/8e6a9efa-6312-44e2-af12-06ad73afbfa5
        //NtVer = values below ORed
        //VIP (NETLOGON_NT_VERSION_IP, 0x20000000): Obsolete, ignored. (But included in examples in documentation)
        //VL (NETLOGON_NT_VERSION_LOCAL, 0x40000000): Indicates that the client is the local machine.
        //VCS (NETLOGON_NT_VERSION_WITH_CLOSEST_SITE, 0x00000010): Indicates that the client is querying for the closest site information. This flag is interpreted by DCs with DC functional level greater than or equal to DS_BEHAVIOR_WIN2008.
        //V5EX (NETLOGON_NT_VERSION_5EX, 0x00000004): Unless overridden by V5EP, this bit instructs the server to respond to LDAP ping and mailslot ping using the NETLOGON_SAM_LOGON_RESPONSE_EX structure.
        private const string NTVER = @"\06\00\00\14";

        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/895a7744-aff3-4f64-bcfa-f8c05915d2e9
        private const string NETLOGON_ATTRIBUTE = "Netlogon";

        #endregion


        #region methods


        public static string SanitizeLdapFilterParameter(
            string value)
        {
            //It is not a good idea to write your own sanitizing code however there do not appear to be any official options for Ldap sanitizers.

            //https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/LDAP_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html
            //OWASP cheatsheet suggests using .NET AntiXSS or LINQ to Active Directory for sanitization but neither link
            //seems to be active any more.

            //System.Text.Encodings.Web nuget does not include LDAP sanitizers.

            //https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4515#section-3
            //The RFC allows all characters to be escaped as UTF8 octets.
            //In this way the code is simple and the "MUST escape" characters (and byte sequences) will definitely be escaped.
            //The trade off is that the Ldap query will be harder to read for troubleshooting.

            if (value == null) return "";

            byte[] utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);

            StringBuilder valueSanitized = new(value.Length * 3);

            foreach (byte b in utf8)
            {
                valueSanitized.Append('\\');
                valueSanitized.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
            }

            return valueSanitized.ToString();

        }


        public static LdapPingResponseEx LdapPingCheckDomain(
            string ldapServer,
            string domain)
        {
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/895a7744-aff3-4f64-bcfa-f8c05915d2e9
            
            return LdapPingForResponseEx(ldapServer, @$"(&(DnsDomain={SanitizeLdapFilterParameter(domain)})(NtVer={NTVER}))");
        }


        public static LdapPingResponseEx LdapPingForResponseEx(
            string ldapServer,
            string filter)
        {

            LdapConnection connection = new(ldapServer)
            {
                AuthType = AuthType.Anonymous
            };

            //https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64900
            connection.SessionOptions.ReferralChasing = ReferralChasingOptions.None;
            

            connection.Bind();

            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/895a7744-aff3-4f64-bcfa-f8c05915d2e9
            SearchRequest request = new(
                "",
                filter,
                SearchScope.Base,
                NETLOGON_ATTRIBUTE);

            SearchResponse pingResponse = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

            connection.Dispose();

            if (pingResponse.Entries.Count > 0)
            {
                if (pingResponse.Entries[0].Attributes.Contains(NETLOGON_ATTRIBUTE))
                {
                    byte[] data = (byte[])pingResponse.Entries[0].Attributes[NETLOGON_ATTRIBUTE][0];

                    return new LdapPingResponseEx(data);
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Invalid Ldap ping request.");
        }

        
        public static bool TryDecompressDnsNames(
            byte[] inputBuffer,
            int inputBufferSize,
            int stringCount,
            ref int position,
            out List<string> outputStrings
            )
        {
            //Correct spec in link below:
            //https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt
            //Algorithm in link below is incorrect:
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/b0ef9479-78d8-40c1-b6d2-0baad834ed39

            outputStrings = new();
            int decompressedCount = 0;
            
            Decoder utf8Decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();

            for (int i = 1; i <= stringCount; i++)
            {
                int nextStringPosition = -1;
                int dnsNameLen = 0;
                bool firstLabel = true;

                byte[] s = new byte[inputBufferSize];

                while (position < inputBufferSize)
                {
                    int labelSize = inputBuffer[position];

                    if (labelSize == 0)
                    {
                        //end of string
                        s[dnsNameLen] = 0;

                        int dnsNameCharLength = utf8Decoder.GetCharCount(s, 0, dnsNameLen, true);
                        char[] dnsName = new char[dnsNameCharLength];

                        utf8Decoder.GetChars(s, 0, dnsNameLen, dnsName, 0, true);

                        outputStrings.Add(new string(dnsName));

                        decompressedCount++;
                        position++;

                        //if we had followed a pointer, then jump back to the position after the first pointer we followed
                        //(Changed from algorithm on learn.microsoft.com link above)
                        if (nextStringPosition >= 0)
                        {
                            position = nextStringPosition;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    else if ((labelSize & 0xC0) != 0)
                    {
                        //pointer to common dns suffix(es)
                        position++;

                        //the first time we are about to follow a pointer, record that the next string starts at the next position
                        //(Changed from algorithm on learn.microsoft.com link above)
                        if (nextStringPosition < 0)
                        {
                            nextStringPosition = position + 1;
                        }

                        labelSize = inputBuffer[position];
                        if (labelSize > inputBufferSize)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                        position = labelSize;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //next label
                        if (labelSize + position >= inputBufferSize)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                        if (firstLabel)
                        {
                            firstLabel = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            s[dnsNameLen] = 0x2E; // 0x2E = .
                            dnsNameLen++;
                        }

                        for (int j = position + 1; j <= position + labelSize; j++)
                        {
                            s[dnsNameLen] = inputBuffer[j];
                            dnsNameLen++;
                        }

                        position += (1 + labelSize);
                    }

                }


                if (i != decompressedCount)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;

        }

        #endregion

    }
```

LdapPingResponseEx class

```
    internal class LdapPingResponseEx
    {
        #region constructors

        public LdapPingResponseEx(
            byte[] data)
        {
            //Format of data in byte[] in link below:
            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/8401a33f-34a8-40ca-bf03-c3484b66265f

            using MemoryStream ms = new(data);

            using BinaryReader reader = new(ms);

            Opcode = reader.ReadUInt16();

            //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/07133ff2-a9a3-4aa9-8896-a7dcb53bdfe9
            //Expecting LOGON_SAM_LOGON_RESPONSE_EX=23 only - which determines the format of the data in the byte[]

            if (Opcode == 25)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown user.");
            }

            if (Opcode != 23)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected LDAP ping response format.");
            }

            Sbz = reader.ReadUInt16();
            Flags = reader.ReadUInt32();
            DomainGuid = new Guid(reader.ReadBytes(16));

            int position = 24;

            if (LdapUtils.TryDecompressDnsNames(data, data.Length, 8, ref position, out List<string> outputStrings))
            {
                DnsForestName = outputStrings[0];
                DnsDomainName = outputStrings[1];
                DnsHostName = outputStrings[2];
                NetbiosDomainName = outputStrings[3];
                NetbiosComputerName = outputStrings[4];
                UserName = outputStrings[5];
                DcSiteName = outputStrings[6];
                ClientSiteName = outputStrings[7];

                NextClosestSiteName = "";

                if (LdapUtils.TryDecompressDnsNames(data, data.Length, 1, ref position, out List<string> outputStringsNext))
                {
                    NextClosestSiteName = outputStringsNext[0];
                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to decompress DNS names from LDAP ping response.");
            }
        }

        #endregion


        #region properties

        public ushort Opcode { get; private set; }
        public ushort Sbz { get; private set; }
        public uint Flags { get; private set; }

        public Guid DomainGuid { get; private set; }

        public string DnsForestName { get; private set; }
        public string DnsDomainName { get; private set; }
        public string DnsHostName { get; private set; }
        public string NetbiosDomainName { get; private set; }
        public string NetbiosComputerName { get; private set; }
        public string UserName { get; private set; }
        public string DcSiteName { get; private set; }
        public string ClientSiteName { get; private set; }
        public string NextClosestSiteName { get; private set; }

        #endregion




    }
```